# Where is Lex Luthor in Man of Steel?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel, lex-luthor

I really missed Lex Luthor type amazing character in *Man of Steel*. I was expecting him to contact General Zod for personal benefits.

With Lex Luthor being the iconic villain for Superman, was he present in "Man of Steel"?

Comment: Luthor is an all time great Superman villain, but he's dominated Superman stories in the medium of film. I was more than happy with Zod and crew as the villains in Man of Steel, and don't worry: LexCorp popped up more than once in the movie, and there's a LOT that can be done in the future if Lex Luthor gets involved with the alien tech or even the body of Zod. Lots of possibilities for a filthy plan from Luthor!

Comment: I wonder where this question gets the downvotes from. Especially if the answer is "Oh yeah, he's there alright".

Comment: I'm so glad that there's now a 'primarily opinion based' flag, I can flag tons of Sachin's poor quality questions

Comment: @Clara Nothing new. There was already 'not constructive' VTC reason in place and questions have crossed them all. I actually restrict the domain to canon..

Comment: @SachinShekhar If you'd just take more effort I wouldn't feel so tempted to flag every question

Comment: @Clara If you find them poor, go ahead to downvote. But, you can't close one because I know whats valid here and whats not.

Comment: “I was expecting him to contact General Zod for personal benefits.” You thought Luthor and Zod would be friends with benefits? You may have been reading too much fan fiction.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Man of Steel makes no direct mention of Lex Luthor, but a panoramic shot does show the existence of the LexCorp tower meaning Lex is probably alive and well. Considering his overexposure during the Christopher Reeve's and Brandon Routh Superman movies, it is just as well he did not show up.**

[image]

Comment: There are actually more shots that show LexCorp logo, in the last part of the movie.

Comment: There is a shot of an exploding fuel truck with the Lexcorp logo on the side.

Comment: Knowing Luthor, he's sitting in the penthouse office of LexCorp Tower plotting how to use the battle below to his own advantage.

Comment: +1, could probably elaborate on this now that BvS has come out, and we have a good idea what Lex was doing.

Answer (score 6):

This was addressed by the film's director in an interview with ScreenCrush. In short, Luthor is in the world, we just didn't happen to see him.

> **Zack:** *What I was going to say about Lex Luthor was, there is a kryptonite question, too, that floats around the Lex Luthor question. Someone asked me if there's no Kryptonite and there's no Lex Luthor. Well, okay, within the parameters of this story there's no kryptonite or Lex Luthor — but that's not to say they don't exist in the world.*
>
> <sub><sup>['Man of Steel' Cast Interview: Why Superman Had to Be Reinvented For a New Generation](http://screencrush.com/man-of-steel-cast-interview/?trackback=tsmclip)</sup></sub>